# ClickOnce application does not start through Process.Start("x.abc") with *.abc associated to the ClickOnce application

Tags: .net, windows-7, clickonce, file-association, processstartinfo

I have successfully developed and deployed a ClickOnce application which registers an associated file extension, for instance `*.abc`. When I click on a file named `x.abc` or if I type `x.abc` from the command prompt, the ClickOnce application starts, and I can retrieve the file through the dedicated API. I can also launch the application programmatically with the following code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ("x.abc");
```

Everything works fine on my Windows Vista 64 bit box.

However, if I try to do exactly the same thing on a Windows 7 (also 64 bit ), I have a very strange problem. Here is what I observe:

1. Manual start of `x.abc` by double-clicking it from the Explorer works.
2. Manual start of `x.abc` from the command prompt works.
3. `Process.Start("x.abc")` does not start the application; however, the process object returned shows that there was not error and that the ClickOnce application somehow exited immediately. But even a `Trace` at the very beginning of the ClickOnce application is never reached.
4. Stranger yet, `Process.Start("x.bat")` with a file `x.bat` containing the single line `x.abc` does not start the ClickOnce application either! Same `x.bat` started from the Explorer works (of course).

Trying to analyse what happens with `ProcMon` was not very helpful, as the ClickOnce process of launching an application is very difficult to follow, from my point of view. I observe `rundll32` getting to work, but no evidence of any failure.

The program which is doing the `Process.Start` is a full trust console application with really nothing fancy.

I can't see what changed with respect to how ClickOnce applications are handled on Windows 7 and why `Process.Start` would not do exactly the same as launching the file from Explorer. It's worth to mention that using more advanced versions of the `Start` method with `ProcessStartInfo` and setting `UseShellExecute` to `true` did not help either.

Starting `cmd` with `Process.Start` and then trying to launch `x.abc` shows exactly the same problem. If I compare the environment settings with a `cmd` started manually, I see differences in how `ProgramFiles` is defined (the first one points to `C:\Program Files (x86)` whereas the second points to `C:\Program Files`). The applications started from my .NET application are started on the 32-bit emulation layer (SysWoW64).

I was able to reproduce the launch failure of `x.abc` by starting a 32-bit version of the command prompt (that is, `%windir%\SysWoW64\cmd.exe`) and then typing `x.abc` at the prompt. I have also found an ugly workaround, which is to start a 64-bit command prompt from the 32-bit environment by launching `%windir%\Sysnative\cmd.exe /C x.abc` instead of `x.abc`.

But I'd rather use a clean way of doing it (or have a Microsoft representative tell me that this is indeed an issue with Windows 7 and/or ClickOncce and that it will be fixed soon).

Comment: Seems like many poeple want to see an answer here. It would be nice if somebody investigate the problem in deep and find the answer.

Comment: It is a good thing to know, that at least, I am not the only one experiencing this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a .BAT based solution, which is easy to implement. Say that you want to launch the ClickOnce application associated with `*.abc` files, then you simply put a file with the same name, but with the `*.bat` extension in the same folder, and then execute the batch file instead. Here is the batch script:

```
if exist "%windir%\sysnative\cmd.exe" goto :mode64bit

rem For a file named "C:\foo\xyz.bat", this will generate the corresponding
rem "C:\foo\xyz.abc" file, built as the concatenation of the drive (%~d0),
rem the folder (%~p0) and the file name (%~n0), plus ".abc":

"%~d0%~p0%~n0.abc"
goto :end

:mode64bit

rem When running in a 32-bit emulation environment on a real 64-bit system,
rem start the 64-bit version of CMD.EXE, and make if start the ".abc" file
rem for us:

C:\Windows\sysnative\cmd.exe /c "%~d0%~p0%~n0.xgen"

:end
```

This could be implemented directly in the caller of the `*.abc` files, but sometimes a batch file helps in the transition...

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you've build your application using 'x32' as the target platform which makes `Process.Start` spawn a x32-bit process. And as I guess Windows 7 stores file associations for 32-bit and 64-bit applications separately.

If you don't have COM or unmanaged 32-bit dependencies you could try building your application for 'Any' target platform instead of 'x32'.

I investigated some further and found that ClickOnce installer creates the following open verb for any associated file extension (GUID is unique per application):

```
rundll32.exe dfshim.dll, ShOpenVerbExtension {dce01888-35e8-4df3-af35-cd971f520d8d} %1
```

Using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), I found that the 32-bit version fails to open `HKCU\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{dce01888-35e8-4df3-af35-cd971f520d8d}` registry key. (the 64-bit version successfully opens it at `HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{dce01888-35e8-4df3-af35-cd971f520d8d}`.)

So for me it is indeed a ClickOnce bug. If I were you, I would use that dirty `%WinDir%\system32\cmd.exe /C test.abc` workaround. (Which appears to work -- tried from x32 Task Manager.)

I've added this issue to the <strike>[Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=521282#details)</strike> (update 2013-02-13: that link is rotten).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. No, I cannot compile my application as a 64-bit application; it would have solved my problem. Now, you are suggesting that file associations are stored separately for x32 and x64 apps. That's weird. Do you have any supporting arguments for this?

Comment: I digged a little deeper and found that even in XP there are logically separate registry branches for file associations but pointing to the same logical location... So far it looks like ClickOnce bug...
Could you please validate whether file association appear in both HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes registry keys?

Comment: On Windows 7, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes does not contain any file association information. And I must stress here that with ClickOnce, the file association does not appear under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes, but in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER branch (e.g. HKCU\Software\Classes\.abc). And no, there is no interesting file association information on the Wow6432Node of HKCU either.

Comment: Ah, yes, I hadn't thought of bringing the issue to the Microsoft Connect site. Let's see if that helps...

Comment: The link to Microsoft Connect issue didn't work. I reported a new issue here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/772457/clickonce-does-not-register-file-associations-for-32bit-apps-on-64bit-system

Comment: For anyone else that finds this answer, the issue appears to be resolved in .net4.5. See a more detailed explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863160/clickonce-program-will-not-start-when-launched-from-shell-execute

Answer (score 0):

That only might start system wide extensions like `.bat` or even `.txt`, but it can't always launch correct programs through extensions.

Instead try this API or a similar alternative in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework):

> FindExecutable : *shell32.dll*   Alias
>   : *"FindExecutableA"* /
>   *"FindExecutableW"*   return type : *int*   parameters :
>   **·** *lpFile* Pointer to a null-terminated string specifying a
>   filename. This can be a document or
>   executable file.
>   **·** *lpDirectory* Pointer to a null-terminated string specifying the
>   default directory.
>   **·** *lpResult* Pointer to a buffer to receive the filename when the
>   function returns. This filename is a
>   null-terminated string specifying the
>   executable file started when an “open”
>   association is run on the file
>   specified in the lpFile parameter.

This returns an integer bigger than zero if success and the char value will contain a [null-terminated string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) that points to the executable that launches this file extension
then you can use it like this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ("program.exe $:\path\x.abc");
```

Instead of `program.exe`, you'll use the result of the API function, and you'll use the path to the file separated with a space just like a command line.

As for the application failure, it might indicate that the program needs administrative rights to run correctly. `cmd` already got administrative rights, so it can make child applications inherit it, but not windows API. `createprocess` allows you to use [LPSECURITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attributes which can help in launching this program with the correct privileges.

Comment: Nice try, but your explanation of why it works on CMD is not correct. All my CMD instances are non privileged. The ones that fail to start the ClickOnce application are running in 32-bit, the ones that succeed are running in 64-bit. I will, however, give your suggestion of how to start the ClickOnce app a try, as soon as I can access the machine which exhibits the failure.

Comment: Sorry, but FindExecutable does not work for ClickOnce file associations. The following sample code works great for other file extensions, though:

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var result = new StringBuilder(512);
    var code   = Program.FindExecutable(@"C:\x.abc", null, result);
    ...
  }
  [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
  static extern IntPtr FindExecutable(string lpFile,
      string lpDirectory, StringBuilder lpResult);
}
Dead end here too...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using *ShellExecute()*; API?

```
        [DllImport("Shell32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr ShellExecute(
        IntPtr hwnd, 
        string lpVerb,
        string lpFile, 
        string lpParameters, 
        string lpDirectory,
        int nShowCmd );

ShellExecute(this.Handle,"open","x.abc","","",3);
```

You could also try the *Shell();* function which is a part of framework

Comment: Process.Start() with UseShellExecute set to true effectively calls to native ShellExecuteEx(). And it will call x32 anyway.

Comment: Indeed, and it does -- alas -- not solve the issue. Thanks anyway for the help.