# Launch a second instance of a WPF application from within the first

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, clickonce

If our standalone app were just a downloaded .exe file (i.e. deployed using windows installer), it would be fairly simple to have a running instance launch a second instance using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`. Unfortunately, our WPF application is deployed VIA [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969776.aspx#Deployment_Technologies), so there's no local file system path to it as far as I know.

How can I launch a second instance of a running ClickOnce app? (And pass it command line parameters if possible.)

Comment: Not a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890634/clickonce-app-does-not-start-through-process-startx-abc-with-abc-associate but it might help

Comment: I'm just curious: why do you need to have two instances of your application?

Comment: @PiotrPtak My application loads up all the details and configuration options for a given 'Program' (A complex object model with roughly 20 modules each with a dozen or so tables, lists and properties). If the user wishes to load up a second 'Program' side by side, the simplest solution is for them to start up a second instance. They want to make that easier by launching a second instance from the first by having a clickable a 'link' wherever another 'Program' is referenced.

Comment: If you know the deployment URL of the application, you can just do a Process.Start on it, and it will install or run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, there IS a local filesystem path when you deploy it via clickonce. Try

```
yourWindow.GetType().Assembly.Location
```

-> this will give you the full path to your assembly.

Comment: No good, that exact code just returns `MUS, Version=6.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`. `MUS` is the name of my application.

Comment: sorry dude, i meant "Location", not "FullName"

Answer (score 6):

You're incorrect: there is a local path, under your local Application Data folder.  Alternatively, you can relaunch the application using the Uri.  In short, you should be able to work out the launch path for your application (maybe using `Environment.CommandLine` or `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName`) as you would for a regular application, and use that.